# Setting up api testing in micronaut with Karate

Tags: karate, micronaut

I have basic hello world, and i want to set up karate to test it works.. so below is my configuration..

karate-config.js

```
function fn() {
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080';
    return {
        AppUrl: url
    };
}
```

TestIT.java class

```
public class TestIT {

    @Karate.Test
    Karate runAllTests() {
        return Karate.run().tags("~@ignore").relativeTo(getClass());
    }

}
```

feature

```
Feature: Info

  Background:
    * url AppUrl

   Scenario: Info OK
     * def response = read('response/response_success.json')
     Given path '/default'
     When method GET

     Then status 200
     Then match response == response
```

controller

```
@Controller("/default")
public class default{

    @Get
    public String default() {

        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

When i run this i get the following output

```
ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.153 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestIT
[ERROR] runAllTests[1]  Time elapsed: 1.149 s  <<< ERROR!
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.graalvm.polyglot.impl.AbstractPolyglotImpl: com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotImpl Unable to get public no-arg constructor
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/graalvm/polyglot/impl/AbstractPolyglotImpl$AbstractManagementDispatch
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.graalvm.polyglot.impl.AbstractPolyglotImpl$AbstractManagementDispatch#
```

Im new to micronaut, anyone have any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: a lot depends on your project structure. maybe you should just use the zip release: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release - if you really need help, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: thanks... I have it working on spring boot, but in micronaut i cant seem to get past this bit

Comment: maybe this thread will help: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2009

Answer (score 1):

added the below dependencies

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
        <artifactId>js-scriptengine</artifactId>
        <version>${graal.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
        <artifactId>js</artifactId>
        <version>${graal.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Also refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/micronaut/README.md